# MySQL - Order by column in a particular sequence

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm looking for the correct MySQL query which will help me to ORDER by 2 fields (Grade and then Surname). When ordering by Grade I want to order in a particular sequence - Gold, then Silver, and finally Bronze.

Below is a simple example of the table

```
Grade  |  Surname  |

Bronze |     B     |    
Gold   |     B     |
Silver |     C     |  
Gold   |     C     |
Gold   |     A     |  
Bronze |     A     |
```

So how would I be able to sort not alphabetically by Grade, but in a particular sequence (ie. Gold, then Silver, then Bronze) and then alphabetically by Surname within that Grade?

I've got my PHP file written and everything is working, I just need some help with the SQL query.

Hope this makes some sense.
Thanks

Comment: Start with reading the manuals http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html --- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html

Answer (score 3):

```
select *
from tab
order by FIND_IN_SET(Grade,'Gold,Silver,Bronze'), Surname
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to do - perfect! Thanks

Comment: I think `field()` makes more sense for this type of query than `find_in_set()`.